# Make a Oracle table column nullable AND set default value to NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to set a NOT NULL column to nullable AND also set default value to NULL

I have tried:

```
alter table T_FUNCIO modify (VALIDATED NULL DEFAULT NULL);
alter table T_FUNCIO modify VALIDATED NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

but none of the 2 works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
ALTER TABLE T_FUNCIO
MODIFY VALIDATED int DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the `NOT NULL` constraint? (Also restating the data type isn't necessary...)

Answer (score 2):

You have the clauses the wrong way around. [From the syntax diagrams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877), the `DEFAULT ...` clause comes *before* the inline constraint. So you can do:

```
alter table T_FUNCIO modify VALIDATED DEFAULT NULL NULL;
```

Note though that if the column is already nullable, which is the default if you didn't specify it at table creation (as is the default value being null of course), then this will still throw "ORA-01451: column to be modified to NULL cannot be modified to NULL". You said your column is currently `NOT NULL` though, so this should be fine.

[Quick db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=33bb16de19eb36b552a5b0859e347152).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a little counter-intuitive:

```
alter table T_FUNCIO modify (VALIDATED NULL)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fa05bf82e2fd352255d0315425180535) is a db<>fiddle.